# Invalid or unqualified reference error using .Cells

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm trying to create excel template (the volume of data will be different from case to case) and it looks like this:

[image]

In every even row is "Customer" and I would like to put in every odd row "Ledger". Basically it should put "Ledger" to every odd row until there are data in column C. I have this code:

```
'========================================================================
' INSERTING LEDGERS for every odd row (below Customer)
'========================================================================

Sub Ledgers()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("C5:C" & LastRow)

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        Set r = rng.Cells(i, -2)
        If i Mod 2 = 1 Then
            r.Value = "Ledger"
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

But it gives me an error msg **Invalid or unqualified reference**. Could you advise me, where I have the error, please?

Many thanks!

Comment: The lines where you are calculating LastRow are using `.Cells` and `.Rows.Count` and `.Range` that are not referring to anything. You need to qualify them with a `Worksheet` reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a command starts with `.` like `.Cells` it expects to be within a `with` statement like …

```
With Worksheets("MySheetName")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("C5:C" & LastRow)
End With
```

So you need to specify the name of a worksheet where the cells are expected to be in.

Not that it would be a good idea to use `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to force that every variable is declared (you missed to declare `i As Long`).

Your code could be reduced to …

```
Option Explicit 

Public Sub Ledgers()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("MySheetName") 
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        'make sure i starts with a odd number
        'here we start at row 5 and loop to the last row
        'step 2 makes it overstep the even numbers if you start with an odd i
        'so there is no need to proof for even/odd
        For i = 5 To LastRow Step 2 
            .Cells(i, "A") = "Ledger" 'In column A
            '^ this references the worksheet of the with-statement because it starts with a `.`
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop with a step 2 to get every other row in your indexer variable.

```
Sub Ledgers()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C5:C" & LastRow)

    For i = 1 To LastRow step 2
        rng.Cells(i, 1) = "Ledger" 'In column A
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: (1) Using  `Option Explicit` and declaring `i As Long` would be a extremely good practice. (2) Also avoid `ActiveSheet` instead always specify a sheet with its name. (3) `.Rows.Count` would still throw an error. Use a `With` statement makes it easier.

Comment: @Peh you beat me to it as I was about to post the .Rows.Count part.  I was going to actually mention about the note for the last row to be odd... i've not had an issue with the last row dictating anything, just ensure that the first row is an odd number, e.g., 5 as in the post's image.  For i = 1 to 6 Step 2, VBA goes 1, 3, 5, break, since there's not another option after to place.

Comment: Of course, but not the scope of the question - That would just be the "step 2". ActiveSheet just makes it run on ActiveSheet, altered that.